# Change Numeric value to Text value? jQuery Gallery

Tags: jquery, arrays, text, slider, numeric

I really like this [jQuery Gallery](http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/02.html)

However, instead of numbers for navigation, I'd like to use words (e.g. Football / Rugby / Athletics).

How do I achieve this?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: The numeric buttons are dynamically generated - depending on the number of images. So you cannot enter texts into the buttons for this gallery.

Comment: IF SOMEONE WANT TO PLAY , here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/mHsuU/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just overwrite them after the gallery is loaded:

```
$(function(){
    // create gallery...

    var titles = ['Football', 'Rugby', 'Athletics', 'asdg', '...'];
    for(var i=0;i<titles.length;i++){
        $('#controls'+(i+1)+' a').html(titles[i]);
    }
});
```

edit:
thanks for the fiddle: seems to work :))) http://jsfiddle.net/mHsuU/2/

Comment: Wow, Andy. That works perfectly. Now to get my head around how you did it :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to modify the source. On the upside, modifying the source looks pretty straight forward. You want to rename the `numericId` option to something like `indexId` to reflect its new purpose. Then you'd add a `indexLabels` option that takes an array value.

Change this:

```
if(options.numeric){
    html += '<ol id="'+ options.numericId +'"></ol>';
```

to

```
if(options.numeric || options.indexLabels){
    html += '<ol id="'+ options.indexId +'"></ol>';
```

And add another branch to this:

```
if(options.numeric){
    for(var i=0;i<s;i++){
    //...
}
```

with something like this:

```
else if(options.indexLabels) {
    // generate the <li>s to match your labels.
}
```

And make sure you change `numericId` to `indexId` everywhere. There are a couple other `if(options.numeric)` checks that you'd want to change to `if(options.numeric || options.indexLabels)` too but not many.

You'd probably want to send a patch to the author as well, that would be polite.

Comment: Totally agree. I will do as soon as I get it working. Nice to be nice :)